# Is it impossible to have NuGet-dependencies at .nuspec of a Roslyn analyzer package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis

**Scenario 1** (Good):

1. Create new VisualStudio solution by Class-Library (.Net Standard 2.0) template.
2. Install any nuGet-package to it (e.g. `Newtonsoft.Json`)
3. Right click on project, *Properties -> Package ->* Mark "*Generate NuGet package on build*"
4. Build solution
5. Check produced `.nupckg` file (by [NuGet package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) of just by 7-Zip) - you'll find, `.nuspec` contains section:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

So, if you install this `.nupckg` to some project, `Newtonsoft.Json` will be installed also. Good!

---

BUT! lets see **Scenaro 2** (Bad):

Lets move the similar way:

1. Create new VisualStudio solution **BUT by "Analyzer with Codefix" template**. (if you examine the `.Package` project, you'll see, it's the same as our 1st example - it's Class-library with target framework .Net Standard 2.0)
2. Install same nuGet-package to it (e.g. `Newtonsoft.Json`)
3. Right click on project `.Package`, *Properties -> Package ->* You'll see, "*Generate NuGet package on build*" is already marked.
4. Build solution
5. Check produced `.nupckg` file (it is at `.Package` project bin/Debug folder) - you'll find, `.nuspec` **DOES NOT** contain section `<dependencies>`.
   So, when you install this `.nupckg` to some project, `Newtonsoft.Json` will **NOT** be installed to it.

---

**My questions:**

- Why is the behavior different?
- Is it possible to have NuGet-dependencies at `.nuspec` of a Roslyn analyzer package?

PS: I've found [a solution](https://www.meziantou.net/packaging-a-roslyn-analyzer-with-nuget-dependencies.htm), but I don't like it, `cos it depreciating the sense of packages management ('cos we just burn dependency dlls into our package). Is this the best solution?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Hi! Yes, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have added

```
<SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>true</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
```

under **xxx.Package** project.

It will prevent all project references and nuget refeferences being packed into `nupkg`(as nuget dependencies) when you pack the **Analyzer.Package** project. And the new `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package is also be prevented.

**In other words**, the node will prevent all referenced projects, installed nuget packages.  And that is designed by the author. The goal of it from the author is to prevent the project references as nuget dependencies for nupkg. Otherwrise, it will turn out an error.

To fix it, it is easy. Just modify `Analyzer.Package.csproj` file:

**1)** change the switch to `false`.

```
<SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>false</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
```

**2)And** then selectively block the project references to be packaged. Use `<PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>` under that.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Analyzer2.CodeFixes\Analyzer2.CodeFixes.csproj">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Analyzer2\Analyzer2.csproj">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**3)** rebuild your project and then you will see the right behavior.

Comment: Thank you, Sara! It works. I just add, you can use `<PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>` for `PackageReference`s also (to prevent some installed NuGet-packages to become a dependency of our produced one)